# Rails 4 Acts as tangible on not saving and showing extra blank tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using [select2 gem](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) with [acts as taggable gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)

I got it working up to the saving into the database.

controller:

```
def skit_params
  params.require(:skit).permit(:idea, :description, :thetag_list).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

form:

```
= f.select :thetag_list, options_for_skit, {}, { id: "thetag_tag", multiple: true }
```

model:

```
class Skit < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :thetags
end
```

coffescript:

```
$('#thetag_tag').select2
  theme: "bootstrap"
```

in my console:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
             "authenticity_token"=>"blah", 
             "skit"=>{"thetag_list"=>["", "tag2", "tag42", "tag320"]}, 
             "commit"=>"Update"}
```

I got my console to show the tags, however, there's always 1 empty tag showing, and none of the tags are saved into the database.

I checked in the db console, `select * from tags;`, nothing is there. I tried to do `= @skit.thetag_list` and nothing shows.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that on my strong parameters, I needed to add

```
:thetag_list => []
```

like so:

```
params.require(:skit).permit(:idea, :description, :thetag_list => []).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
```

Its also weird that this `[]` needs to be the last one or you'll get an error, I'm not sure why this happens, example:

```
params.require(:skit).permit(:idea, : thetag_list => [], :description).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
```

will give an error. Maybe someone can chime in on this issue?